# Sub-view change event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js, ecmascript-6

I switched from using Grunt as my build tool to Webpack. The transition was *relatively* smooth. At least it was until I noticed the following issue I'm having.

I currently have many Backbone views in my application and am using the factory method to instantiate and garbage collect as I move along. After converting my project to Webpack though one of my subviews `change` events is no longer firing (that is to say that it was firing previously so I know it worked at some point). The subviews are generated when the user enters the parent view in a for loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<this.dayIds.length; i++) {
  this.timeSelectorDayViews[i] = new timeSelectorDay({
    el: '#timePickersWrapper',
    data: {
      time: this.model.get(this.dayIds[i]),
      date: moment(this.model.get('weekStartDate')).add(i, 'd')
    }
  }).render();
}
```

And here's the subview code:

```
'use strict';

import { app } from '../app';

export const timeSelectorDay = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(data) {
      this.options = data;
      this.options.data.formattedDate = moment(this.options.data.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      this.events = _.clone(this.events) || {};
      var inputEventKey = 'change' + ' .input-' + this.options.data.formattedDate;
      this.events[inputEventKey] = 'inputCheck';
      this.totalHours = 0;
    },
    render: function(){
      this.template = _.template(app.createTemplate('templates/timeSelectorDay.tpl', this.options.data));
      $(this.options.el).append(this.template({}));
      this.delegateEvents();
      this.checkTotalTime();
      return this;
    },
    inputCheck: function() {
      ...
      ... //Doing some computational logic here
      ...
      app.event_bus.trigger('totalTime');
      app.event_bus.trigger('inputChange');
    },
    checkTotalTime: function(){
      var totalTimeDiv = document.getElementById('totalHours-'+this.options.data.formattedDate);
      var totalTime = parseFloat(totalTimeDiv.innerHTML);
      if (totalTime>0) {
        totalTimeDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#69a776';
      } else {
        totalTimeDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#dd3c3c';
      }
      this.totalHours = totalTime;
    }
});
```

It also may be of worth noting that I'm generating the event in a non normal backbone fashion via string concatenation and altering the events array. The reason for this being that I need to assign unique ids to my HTML elements.

My first thoughts were that maybe with the new webpack implementation for some reason the events were not being attached properly. I tried resolving this via calling `this.delegateEvents()` with no success.

My next thought was that maybe the events are out of the view scope or are being detached somehow so I confirmed that the `input` element was event attachable within the view. Also not the issue.

I think what's the most puzzling about this situation is if I change that `change` event to a `click` event it works perfectly fine and fires the corresponding function:

```
var inputEventKey = 'click' + ' .input-' + this.options.data.formattedDate;
```

UPDATE (Additional Data):

subview template:

```
<div id="timeselectors-<%= formattedDate%>" class="row small-collapse medium-uncollapse margin-bottom border">
  <div class="small-12 columns"><%= moment(date).format('dddd') %> (<%= moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY') %>)</div>
  <div class="small-10 columns">
    <div class="row small-collapse">
      <div class="small-5 medium-2 columns morning">
        <input id="morning-login" class="input-<%= formattedDate%>" type="text" id="example" placeholder="Login"/>
      </div>
      <div class="small-1 medium-1 columns morning dash"> - </div>
      <div class="small-5 medium-2 columns morning">
        <input id="morning-logout" class="input-<%= formattedDate%>" type="text" id="example" placeholder="Logout"/>
      </div>
      <div class="small-5 medium-2 medium-offset-1 columns afternoon">
        <input id="afternoon-login" class="input-<%= formattedDate%>" type="text" id="example" placeholder="Login"/>
      </div>
      <div class="small-1 medium-1 columns afternoon dash"> - </div>
      <div class="small-5 medium-2 columns afternoon end">
        <input id="afternoon-logout" class="input-<%= formattedDate%>" type="text" id="example" placeholder="Logout"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="totalHours-<%= formattedDate%>" class="small-2 columns hours">
    <%= time %>
  </div>
</div>
```

As for my webpack config I'm using gulp as my webpack driver but here's the config I pass into the webpack instantiation:

```
{
  entry: './src/app/client-app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/app/js'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      '_': 'lodash'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel'] },
    ]
  }
}
```

webpack entry file:

```
// import 'babel-polyfill';
import 'script!jquery';
import 'script!lodash';
// import 'script!what-input';
import Backbone from 'backbone';
import 'backbone-validation';
import 'script!jquery.cookie';
import 'script!moment';
import 'script!fastclick';
import 'script!clndr';
import 'script!timepicker';
import 'script!foundation-sites/js/foundation';

import { app } from './app';

$(document).ready(function () {
    app.init();

  //Initialize Foundation
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

In addition to all that I should've mentioned that all the code is publicly available on github if you wanted to clone down the repo and reproduce the issue:

https://github.com/wootencl/timeSheetApplication/tree/ProjectRewrite

UPDATE (11/14/16): After unsuccesfully trying to replicate this within a controlled environment (plunkr, etc.) I decided to start to slowly work backwards to diagnose the issue. So far I've discovered that the issue arises not from webpack but from the modularization of my project. I went from a brash script tag per file to the root `index.js` with all the dependent modules imported and this seems to be where things start to go wrong.

Comment: Without the template and/or the webpack config, or a [mcve], it's not possible to spot the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @EmileBergeron! Going to change my file to reflect your recommendations and report back.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't spot the problem with the provided code, I can start to point some things that could be improved.

To start, I would pass custom options directly, there's no need for a nested `data` object.

```
this.timeSelectorDayViews[i] = new timeSelectorDay({
    el: '#timePickersWrapper',
    time: this.model.get(this.dayIds[i]),
    date: moment(this.model.get('weekStartDate')).add(i, 'd')
}).render();
```

Then in the sub-view, I would move the `events` changes into the constructor, before Backbone creates calls `setElement` with the provided `el`.

```
export const timeSelectorDay = Backbone.View.extend({
    // The template should be compiled once here, then used in the render function.
    template: _.template(app.createTemplate('templates/timeSelectorDay.tpl')),

    constructor: function(options) {
        this.options = _.extend({
            /* default options could go here */
        }, options); // make a copy and use it.
        this.options.formattedDate = moment(this.options.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

        // change the events hash before delegating the events.
        // the constructor is a good place for this.
        this.events['change .input-' + this.options.formattedDate] = 'inputCheck';

        Backbone.View.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.totalHours = 0;
    },
    render: function() {
        // use the $el directly, avoid global jQuery.
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.options));
        this.checkTotalTime();
        return this;
    },
    inputCheck: function() {
        // Doing some computational logic here
        // ...snip...
        app.event_bus.trigger('totalTime');
        app.event_bus.trigger('inputChange');
    },
    checkTotalTime: function() {
        // use Backbone's jQuery shortcut instead of the Javascript native
        // api, it's easier and it is scoped to the view's el.
        var totalTimeDiv = this.$('#totalHours-' + this.options.formattedDate),
            totalTime = parseFloat(totalTimeDiv.html());
        // I would avoid changing the css in favor of toggling a class.
        // It would keep the style separated from the logic.
        totalTimeDiv.css('background-color', totalTime > 0 ? '#69a776' : '#dd3c3c');
        this.totalHours = totalTime;
    }
});
```

Comment: Still no luck with this approach sadly. Though I think your suggestions on cleaning up my view will hopefully get me pointed in the right direction. Will report back later tonight/tomorrow with my findings. Thanks again for trying to help!

Comment: @wootencl It's a pleasure to help ;) Another question, is it really related to webpack? What if you take only the relevant views/templates and make a minimal runnable snippet?

Comment: Good question. I assumed it was webpack because I started noticing the issue when I migrated from Grunt to webpack though that might not be the case. If I can't figure it out tonight I'll probably try to create a plunkr (or something similar) and see if I can recreate the issue.

Comment: @wootencl it's a really good way to find a bug, to remove more and more of the surrounding complexity, until you're isolating the culprit.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response! Got busy with outside work. Updated my answer with some additional info. Still digging as of the moment